# Can we use vector as the variable in an autoregressive model?

Tags: regression, time-series, vector-autoregression

I have a vector variable with 50 time periods. I believe the vector variable changes over time but also has a static component. I am looking for a model similar to an AR(1) model that can provide me with coefficients to indicate how the variable changes over time, as well as residuals to indicate volatility over time. I have considered a VAR model, but my variable has a high number of dimensions, making interpretation difficult.

Does anyone have any suggestions or advice? Thank you in advance!